# Function returning blank

Tags: c++, oop

I was trying to test very basic OO in c++, but I ran into a problem. I was writing the following classes:

Actor Class:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Actor
{
private:
    void setName(std::string inputName);

public:
    std::string name{};
    
    Actor(std::string inputName = "Actor");

    std::string getName();

};
```

```
#include "Actor.h"

Actor::Actor(std::string inputName)
{
    setName(inputName);
}

void Actor::setName(std::string inputName)
{
    name = inputName;
}

std::string Actor::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Character Class

```
#pragma once
#include "Actor.h"

class Character : public Actor
{
public:
    int maxHealth{};
    int currentHealth{};

    Character(std::string inputName = "Character", int inputHealth = 100);
    int getCurrentHealth();

};
```

```
#include "Character.h"

Character::Character(std::string inputName, int inputHealth) : 
    Actor{inputName}, maxHealth{inputHealth}, currentHealth{inputHealth}
{

}

int Character::getCurrentHealth()
{
    return currentHealth;
}
```

Player Class

```
#pragma once
#include "Character.h"
class Player : public Character
{
public:
    Player();

};
```

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player():
    Character{"Player", 200}
{
    
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

int main()
{
    Player a{};

    std::cout << "Actor name is: " + a.getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Player health is: " + a.getCurrentHealth() << std::endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, `a.getName()` prints normally, returning the string "Player". However, `a.getCurrentHealth` does not print. Not just the value, but the entire sentence "Player health is: " is not printing. Any idea on what's happening?

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `std::cout << "Actor name ...`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It prints blank as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no operation in C++ that adds an integer to a string. Use `<<` not `+` to get the output you want.

```
std::cout << "Player health is: " << a.getCurrentHealth() << std::endl;
```

What your code is doing is *pointer arithmetic*. The string literal was interpreted as a `char` pointer, the health value was then added to that pointer and the resulting address (which could have been pointing anywhere) was printed as if it pointed to a C style string.